# Apple wallet pass expiring the pass

Tags: ios, node.js, passkit, apple-wallet

Adding the dates as below

```
        relevantDate : "2023-09-19T16:30-17:00",
        expirationDate:"2023-09-19T16:30-17:00",
```

But the pass file is not appearing as expired.
I have tried both dates no clear documentation from Apple Developer website. Server side using nodeJs